# How to call RESTful web service using TIBCO GI?

Tags: tibco-gi

I have created login page using Tibco GI and want to integrate this page with Restful web service for authentications.
can any one know how to integrate restful web service with tibco GI?

Regards,
Bikkie

Answer (score 0):

Tibco cannot, you need to develop a java class that do it for you and use it inside Tibco.